# Create db schema from migrations with Yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I have an application that is built with Yii framework. It has lots of migrations and now I want to generate a db schema, so it would be possible for other people to install the application without applying all the migrations.
In Ruby on Rails db/schema.rb contains the sum of all migrations. I want to do the same in Yii, but protected/data/schema.mysql.sql doesn't seem to be changing after migrations are applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create your own sql script and import it.

Have a look at the [dlhelperdatabase](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dlhelperdatabase/) extension, it will help you do what you want!